# Cannot Change Password: "network problem" or "temporary connectivity issue"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, password

I currently cannot log into Outlook or Microsoft Teams on my macOS laptop because my work Microsoft account password has expired.

Outlook prompts me to change my password. When I enter my old and new password, I get the error:

> We tried to update your password, but couldn't sync with your workplace because of a network problem. Try again in a few minutes. If it still doesn't work, contact your admin and provide the detailed error information. View details

When I visit the company's SharePoint site, I can log in with the "expired" password. When I go to change it, I get the error:

> #### We could not change your password
>
> We're sorry, but we cannot change your password at this time. This is due to a temporary connectivity issue, so if you try again later, changing your password may succeed.
>
> If the issue persists, please contact your admin to change your password for you.
>
> Cancel

Why is this password change not working on my company's SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable self-service password reset and password writeback on Azure AD.
Take a reference to the following articles to enable them:

[Tutorial: Enable users to unlock their account or reset passwords using Azure Active Directory self-service password reset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr)

[Tutorial: Enable Azure Active Directory self-service password reset writeback to an on-premises environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr-writeback)